# change link colour blue into white

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview

I am having a web view, I want to change the link colour blue into white . below the html tag I am changing font its working good. please tell me what is the html tag for changing the link colour.

```
 NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                             @"<html>"
                                            "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                           "body { background-color:transparent; color: #eadfa8;font-family:Arial; font-size:24; }"
                                           "</style>"
                                           "<body>"
                                           "<p>%@</p>"
                                           "</body></html>", content1];

            [webview loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS add `a{color:white}`

```
NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                             @"<html>"
                                            "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                           "body { background-color:transparent; color: #eadfa8;font-family:Arial; font-size:24; }"
"a {color: white;}"

                                           "</style>"
                                           "<body>"
                                           "<p>%@</p>"
                                           "</body></html>", content1];

            [webview loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all links color to white, you can add this in your css
:

```
a:link{text-color:#ffffff}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                             @"<html>"
                                            "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                           "body { background-color:transparent; color: #eadfa8;font-family:Arial; font-size:24; }"
                                           "body.a:link {color:#FFFFFF !important;}"
                                           "</style>"
                                           "<body>"
                                           "<p>%@</p>"
                                           "</body></html>", content1];
```

You can set link color like below :

```
"body.a:link {color:#FFFFFF !important;}"
```

Comment: still it is in blue .. why ?